# Count the size of items in Json Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I am constructing a JSON response as below :

```
{
  "G5LDUHRPEEA6B-39CFBWYA": [],
  "JMSK0DKOEEA0UXMY750O3W": [],
  "ISVN8JF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": LA,
      "hello": "OUTSIDE"

    },
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": Chicago,
      "hello": “Inside"
    },
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": Austin,
      "hello": “Inside"
    }
  ],
  "VRG0IJF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [{

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": Chicago,
      "hello": “Inside"
    },
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": Austin,
      "hello": “Inside"
    }],
  "OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [],
  "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": []
  }
```

I want to count the total number of items in the array , including the internal array and disregard if the internal array is empty like       "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": []
I tried  _.size(collection) but I need to know how to remove empty internal ones.Thanks in advance

Comment: What kinda of things have you tried? Can you show us the code that didn't work?

Comment: I tried Object.keys(arr).length) ,but did not give a result

Comment: What do you mean by "internal array"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and loop through to sum up the lengths of the arrays - see demo below:

```js
var object={"G5LDUHRPEEA6B-39CFBWYA":[],"JMSK0DKOEEA0UXMY750O3W":[],"ISVN8JF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA":[{"delloData":"1478644629","ref":"75","dataType":"String","somePart":"LA","hello":"OUTSIDE"},{"delloData":"1478644629","ref":"75","dataType":"String","somePart":"Chicago","hello":"Inside"},{"delloData":"1478644629","ref":"75","dataType":"String","somePart":"Austin","hello":"Inside"}],"VRG0IJF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA":[{"delloData":"1478644629","ref":"75","dataType":"String","somePart":"Chicago","hello":"Inside"},{"delloData":"1478644629","ref":"75","dataType":"String","somePart":"Austin","hello":"Inside"}],"OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA":[],"SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA":[]}

var result = Object.keys(object).reduce(function(p,c){
  p+= object[c].length;
  return p;
},0);


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use lodash for counting all the items in the arrays:

```js
var obj = {
  "G5LDUHRPEEA6B-39CFBWYA": [],
  "JMSK0DKOEEA0UXMY750O3W": [],
  "ISVN8JF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "LA",
      "hello": "OUTSIDE"

    },
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Chicago",
      "hello": "Inside"
    },
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Austin",
      "hello": "Inside"
    }
  ],
  "VRG0IJF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [{

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Chicago",
      "hello": "Inside"
    },
    {

      "delloData": "1478644629",
      "ref": "75",
      "dataType": "String",
      "somePart": "Austin",
      "hello": "Inside"
    }],
  "OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [],
  "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": []
  }

var result = _.flatMap(_.values(obj)).length

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash:

```
function calcLength(obj) {
  return _(obj)
    .values() // get the sub arrays
    .map('length') // map them to length
    .sum(); // sum the length
}
```

```js
function calcLength(obj) {
  return _(obj)
    .values() // get the sub arrays
    .map('length') // map them to length
    .sum(); // sum the length
}

var obj = {
  "G5LDUHRPEEA6B-39CFBWYA": [],
  "JMSK0DKOEEA0UXMY750O3W": [],
  "ISVN8JF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [{

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "LA",
    "hello": "OUTSIDE"

  }, {

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Chicago",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }, {

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Austin",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }],
  "VRG0IJF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [{

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Chicago",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }, {

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Austin",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }],
  "OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [],
  "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": []
};

console.log(calcLength(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6 you can use `Object.values()` to get all sub arrays, then spread and concat them. If you have a large object, this might be an expensive operation. Go with the lodash solution, or a simple Array#reduce:

```
const calcLength = (obj) => [].concat(...Object.values(obj)).length;
```

```js
const calcLength = (obj) => [].concat(...Object.values(obj)).length;

var obj = {
  "G5LDUHRPEEA6B-39CFBWYA": [],
  "JMSK0DKOEEA0UXMY750O3W": [],
  "ISVN8JF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [{

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "LA",
    "hello": "OUTSIDE"

  }, {

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Chicago",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }, {

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Austin",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }],
  "VRG0IJF1EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [{

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Chicago",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }, {

    "delloData": "1478644629",
    "ref": "75",
    "dataType": "String",
    "somePart": "Austin",
    "hello": "Inside"
  }],
  "OGAESJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": [],
  "SC9OMJF2EEAD3W398ZNOSA": []
};

console.log(calcLength(obj));
```